# rsync include only directory pattern

Tags: rsync

I want to include only directories named `*cache*`, and all files and subdirectories under them.
How to write `rync --include --exclude`?

```
        source                          dest        
        ├── a                           │   
        ├── b                           ├── b   
        │   └── d                       │   └── d       
        │       └── e                   │       └── e           
        │           └── cache           │           └── cache                   
        ├── c                           ├── c   
        │   └── f                       │   └── f       
        │       └── npm_cache           │       └── npm_cache                   
        ├── g                           ├── g   
        │   └── cache_stores            │   └── cache_stores                    
        ├── h                           ├── h   
        │   └── cache                   │   └── cache           
        │       └── i                   │       └── i           
        │           └── j               │           └── j               
        └── k                           │   
            └── l                       │
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This should work:

```
--include='*/'
--include='*cache*/**'
--exclude='*'
--prune-empty-dirs
```

That says:

- Include all folders (this is necessary to search inside them).
- Include all files with "cache" in the name of a parent directory.
- Exclude everything else.
- Prune away any folders that were copied but turned out to contain no caches. Unfortunately, this also removes any empty folders within cache directories, but hopefully that's not important to you.

Comment: I think it is `--prune-empty-dirs`

Comment: So it is. Not sure what I was thinking there?

Comment: It's also possible you need `**` before "cache".

Comment: This doesnt work as expected

Answer (score 1):

I have accepted ams's answer, but if you don't know rsync `--include --exclude` syntax (I don't), get an explicit file list with `find` first.

```
cd source
find . | grep /.*cache.*/ | rsync --files-from=- source dest
```